# Need to show file names of attached files, Files are uploaded on a separate page opened with window.open

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload

In my ASP.net 2.0 application, I am allowing user to upload files on a separate page which is opened using window.open from the main page.
Once that window is closed I want to show the uploaded file names on the main page without submitting the main page.

Answer (score 0):

The opened window can reference the main page like this with JavaScript:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("divlabeletc").value = newfilename;
```